# Moving resources between CloudFormation stacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform

Lets imagine that i have a cloudformation stack with 2 EC2 instances 1 S3 bucket and 1 dynamoDb table.
Everything is good with this stack until we decide to do some refactoring and split this stack into two stacks. Stack A that has only 2 EC2 instances and Stack B that has 1 S3 bucket and 1 dynamoDb table.

My question is: what is the best way to do that without destroying and re creating the resources or doing migration? (i am looking for a solution similar to terraform move state).

Could you please share how you organise your stacks and how you refactor them.

Comment: This is a difficult problem to solve generally. I don't think there's a solution. Also see https://sanderknape.com/2018/08/two-years-with-cloudformation-lessons-learned/#moving-and-renaming-your-resources-isn-t-all-too-great

Comment: @jarmod, thanks for the link, do you know if this problem is fully resolved by terraform state move? i am reading their documentation, it looks exactly what we basically need, i am just afraid that i might be missing something.

Comment: I’m not familiar with the Terraform feature, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no mechanism in CloudFormation to move objects/resources from 1 stack to another.

*If* you had used [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) to deploy your resources, then yes, you could use `terraform state mv` to move resources from one state file to a different state file. A Terraform *state file* is associated with a single Terraform deployment, so you you could think of it as being analogous to how CloudFormation stores its version of what's deployed in a stack.

Note that Terraform state moves are not the simplest things in the world and AFAIK there is no GUI interface to assist with *moves*. Make backups and set aside time for testing.

There is, however, a project called [Terraboard](https://camptocamp.github.io/terraboard/) that is a GUI that can help you *inspect* the state file.

Answer (score 6):

Moving resources between stacks is now supported for some resources including DynamoDb, EC2 instances and S3 buckets.   The aws docs at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html give the full detail and instructions starting with:

> Using the resource import feature, you can move resources between, or refactor, stacks. You need to first add a Retain deletion policy to the resource you want to move to ensure that the resource is preserved when you remove it from the source stack and import it to the target stack.
>
> Important
>
> Not all resources support import operations. See [Resources that
> Support Import Operations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) before you remove a resource from your
> stack. If you remove a resource that doesn't support import operations
> from your stack, you can't import the resource into another stack or
> bring it back into the source stack.